# D3.3: Unable to represent time correctly into X-axis as Hour:Min:Sec format?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a list of dictionaries to represent data in a chart form using D3, but graph doesnt shows correctly as I am unable to parse time in a H:M:S format.

Here is the few lines:

```
           var data= [{ val: "0", timestamp : "10:20:45"},
                 { val: "0", timestamp : "10:21:45" },
                { val: "0" , timestamp : "10:22.45"},
                { val: "0" , timestamp : "10:20:45"},
              { val : "267", timestamp : "10:21:45" },
              { val : "0", timestamp : "10:22.45"},
                 { val: "0" , timestamp : "10:24:45"},
              { val : "128", timestamp : "10:25:45" },
               { val : "0", timestamp : "10:30.45"},
              ]
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;

          // Set the ranges
            var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, graphWidth]);
              var y = d3.scale.linear().range([graphHeight, 0]);

         // Define the axes
          var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                   .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
             .orient("left").ticks(5);
```

I think , I have covered pretty much every thing , but it somehow doesn't work. I am new using D3 , need some help.
full code- https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/p8oxdcey/

Comment: Don't you think there should be date associated with this time as well ? Can you please create a jsfiddle for your current working instance ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/p8oxdcey/ here is the link, could you please help

Comment: I looked into this question yesterday, don't you think we should have date associated with time ?? How do you want x axis to be ??

Comment: in a Hour: time : sec format, I want current date data only

Comment: or otherwise, tell me the correct format to parse the time @Prince

Comment: Added my answer, hope it will help you. I have also given link to one more chart and i think that might help you to reshape your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to normalize your data so that you have unique keys and you can see a single point for a particular time. For that you need to use `d3.nest`.

It will create a `newData` where `key` will be the time and `values` will be the value you want to show.

```js
var dataset = [{
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:20:45"
  },
  {
    val: "34",
    timestamp: "10:20:46"
  },
  {
    val: "45",
    timestamp: "10:20:47"
  },
  {
    val: "54",
    timestamp: "10:20:48"
  },
  {
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:21:45"
  },
  {
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:22.45"
  },
  {
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:20:45"
  },
  {
    val: "267",
    timestamp: "10:21:45"
  },
  {
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:22.45"
  },
  {
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:24:45"
  },
  {
    val: "128",
    timestamp: "10:25:45"
  },
  {
    val: "0",
    timestamp: "10:30.45"
  },
]

data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.timestamp
  })
  .rollup(function(leaves) {
    return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
      return +d.val
    })
  })
  .entries(dataset)

const firstValue = 0,
  lastValue = data.length,
  middleValue = Math.round((firstValue + lastValue) / 2),
  secondVaue = Math.round((firstValue + middleValue / 2)),
  thirdValue = Math.round((middleValue + lastValue) / 2)


var width = 500,
  height = 200;

var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.key
  }))
  .range([50, width - 50])
  .padding(0.5);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  }) * 1.1])
  .range([height - 50, 10]);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.key)
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return yScale(d.value)
  });

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", line(data))
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2")
  .attr("fill", "none");

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

if (data.length > 5) {
  const firstValue = 0,
    lastValue = data.length - 1,
    middleValue = Math.round((firstValue + lastValue) / 2),
    secondValue = Math.round((firstValue + middleValue / 2)),
    thirdValue = Math.round((middleValue + lastValue) / 2),
    tickArr = [data[firstValue].key, data[secondValue].key, data[middleValue].key, data[thirdValue].key, data[lastValue].key];

  xAxis
    .tickValues(tickArr);
}

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,150)")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .attr("class", "yAxis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it will resolve your issue.

I would suggest you to look into this example, it might help you to reshape your chart idea. https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f

Updated code as per ask - https://jsfiddle.net/wkb8vzjp/

Comment: one more thing, I have to ask , I have to scale time also because if that is more then x axis length will also increase, how to show only 5 values in x axis

Comment: I want to take only 5 values of time in a interval, could you please help @Prince

Comment: We cannot use ticks on ordinal or point scale, thats why its not working. Give me some time, will need to write some our logic

Comment: Hi Ankit, Updated the answer as per new ask, please check. Happy to see that you rejected my solution even i answered your first ask. This is an add on question on top of that.

Comment: Did it solve your issue ? we can discuss over chat if need more help. You can join this room for chat  - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209320/d3-line-chart

Comment: If i want to show the graph as a container like previously graphDiv, it is not showing the graph

Comment: can you please join the chat.

Comment: I am unable to send messages on the chat,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209321/discussion-between-anki2244-and-prince).

Comment: @Primce can you come to the chat

Comment: I have joined the chat